# Proper place for error message/hint in a html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple standard form and am planning to use javascript's

`document.getElementById("idname").innerHTML = "hint/error message";`

to change/display my error message on the form.

Where is the proper place to put the error message on the form?

Inside label? Next to label?

Do I put it in a div or a span?

(I would like the error message to display to the right of the input field.)

Here is my form below:

```
<form id="registerForm" method="POST" action="register_post.php">

  <p class="form-registerUserName">
    <label for="registerUserName">User Name</label>
    <span class="required">*</span>
    <input
        id="registerUserName"
        name="registerUserName"
        type="text"
        size="24"
        maxlength="24"
        value="<?php echo $_SESSION['registerUserName'];?>"
        onkeyup="validateName()"
        onblur="validateName()"
     >
   </p>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is up to you and your requirements

Comment: What is the most standard or prevalent way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is good if you use a div as a wrapper and have the error message in a label, and put that beside the input box.

Say : 
    
        User Name
        *
        "
            onkeyup="validateName()"
            onblur="validateName()"
         >

**CSS**

```
input{
    display: inline-block;
}
label.error_msg{
    display: none;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: So I create a second label element for the error message? ok to have 2 label elements for same input?

Comment: There is no fixed convention as such in terms of using label, span, p or div for the error message. You can use any of them keeping in mind the css changes that you need to make depending on the element you choose

Comment: Any hint for the css to position the second label to the right of the input box? (first label is positioned above the box)

Comment: second label should always be after the textbox, so that when it is visible, it will be displayed just next to your textbox

Answer (score 1):

You can display a error MSG for validation on Div so that you can easily manage a div show/hide using javascript.

eg.

```
<div class="error" style="display: none; float:left; width:100%;" id="nameError">Please Enter User Name *</div>
<div><input type="text" id="username" name='username' class="textcss validate" style="width:95%"  placeholder="Your name can not be blank" ></div>
```

now check onsubmit its fill or not and show and hide the error div so you css will in proper form